# How to fix my code for the POST function can communicate to the server?

Tags: javascript, server, httprequest, internal-server-error

If I make a post to the server the browser's developer console throw it away that:  'http-client.js:28 POST http://todoapp.test/api/create 500 (Internal Server Error)', but if I send it to the same url with POSTMAN, the server save the data.

Here is my POST function:

> ```
> export class HttpClient {
>     constructor(url) {
>         this.url = url;
>         this.xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
>         this.xhr.onloadend = (event) => {
>             return this.xhr.response;
>         }
>     }
>
>     setHeader(header) {
>         this.xhr.setRequestHeader(header.name, header.value);
>     }
>
>      post(async, data, header) {
>          return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
>             this.xhr.open('POST', this.url + 'create', async);
>             this.xhr.setRequestHeader(header.name, header.value);
>             this.xhr.send(data);
>             resolve(this.xhr.response);
>         });
>     }
> ```

Where is the problem on the server or on my code?
And how can I fix that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should set contentType: "application/json" might be help please try this

Comment: I used this in the other class 
'this.header = { 'Content-Type' : 'application/json' };'